# Use php CAS to retrieve/scrape a page once authenticated

Tags: php, authentication, cas

I'm trying to figure out if, and if so, how, to scrape a page that needs a CAS authentication by the user. What I have managed to do is authenticate my 3rd party application (web app) with the CAS server and can retrieve the CAS user object.

Once this is done however, I want to get scrape a page which is accessible for all logged in users. Much like you would be able to do if you logged in normally.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

CAS supports a concept known as proxying which allows one client application to connect to the second client application acting on behalf of the authenticated to the first application.

Check out the [PHP CAS documentation](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS+examples#phpCASexamples-ACASproxy/) for more details.

Make sure you use the CAS 2.0 protocol.

Comment: Thank you John for answering. I've been looking through the documentation but I can't really figure it out. Is this example what I'm describing? https://github.com/Jasig/phpCAS/blob/master/docs/examples/example_proxy_GET.php

Comment: Yes. It looks like PHPCAS takes care of all the work for you to access a protected resource as a proxy. You just pass in the service url.